# how to force another user to sign out with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

As an admin user, I can only sign out myself. How can I force another user to sign out after he has been fired in a employee website with devise?

What is the best approach? And where should I start?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Devise allows you to sign in and sign out users forcefully.

Sign in a user that already was authenticated.

```
sign_in :user, @user                      # sign_in(scope, resource)
sign_in @user
```

Similarly you can sign out the user as

```
sign_out :user     # sign_out(scope)
sign_out @user     # sign_out(resource)
```

For more information please refer to this [link](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_out-instance_method)

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable
def timeout_in
 if self.active? 
  1.year
 else
  1.second
  end
 end
end
```

Thus, a particular user with inactive status, who has been fired, got forcing sign out if he doesn't hit his screen within one second.

This might not be the best solution. However, it works for me as admin to force all users with inactive status to sign out.